# Browser-sync [proxy error] ECONNREFUSED on initial load ONLY

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am getting a really weird behaviour with my gulp and browser-sync setup.

When I run my `gulp serve` task the gulp task runs and build everything and opens the web browser, it just stays there spinning. I go to check the console and I'm getting this error.

```
[gulp-bs] Watching files...
[gulp-bs] [proxy error] connect ECONNREFUSED
Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/<database name>
```

Now what is interesting is when I go and hit that URL with the browser bar to load the application, everything loads properly.

Why does it happen **only the first** time but subsequent reloading the browser URL works?

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error, I don't want to keep reloading the browser after the initial load.

My gulp setup for browser-sync is shown below:

```
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"browser-sync": "^2.7.13"
```

The function is called from a `nodemon` gulp-task.

```
function serve(isDev) {
    var options = {
        script: config.nodeServer,
        delayTime: 1,
        env: {
            "PORT": config.port,
            "NODE_ENV": isDev ? "dev" : "production"
        }
    };

    $.nodemon(options)
        .on("restart", function(ev) {
            log("*** nodemon restarted.");
            log("files changed on restart: " + ev);

            setTimeout(function() {
                browserSync.notify("Reloading now...");
                browserSync.reload({
                    stream: false
                });
            }, config.browserReloadDelay);
        })
        .on("start", function() {
            log("*** nodemon started.");
            startBrowserSync(isDev);
        })
        .on("crash", function() {
            log("*** nodemon crashed due to unexpected reason(s).");
        })
        .on("exit", function() {
            log("*** nodemon exited successfully!.");
        });
}
```

Browser-sync function:

```
function startBrowserSync(isDev) {
    log("*** Starting browser sync");
    if (browserSync.active || args.nosync) {
        return;
    }

    if (isDev) {
        gulp.watch([config.styles], ["styles"])
            .on("change", function(event) {
                changeEvent(event);
            });
        gulp.watch([config.js], ["wiredep"])
            .on("change", function(event) {
                changeEvent(event);
            });
    } else {
        gulp.watch([config.styles, config.js, config.html], ["optimize", browserSync.reload])
            .on("change", function(event) {
                changeEvent(event);
            });
    }

    var options = {
        proxy: "localhost:" + config.port,
        port: 8000,
        files: isDev ? [
            config.client + "**/*.*",
            "!" + config.styles,
            config.css + "**/*.css"
        ] : [],
        ghostMode: {
            clicks: true,
            scroll: true,
            location: false,
            forms: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        logFileChanges: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        logPrefix: "gulp-bs",
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 1,
    };

    browserSync(options);
}
```

The `config.port` value is set to 3000 read from a configuration file.

Comment: Have you figured out anything yet?

Comment: @Qwerty, I don't use `gulp` anymore these days. There are better alternatives.